# Google Maps v3 - Accuracy

Tags: google-maps

I'm passing the google maps API a lat/long detected via my Android mobile device.  However, as I sit at my same desk it'll often give different addresses within the same sitting although I haven't moved locations...

Sometimes it gives me the correct exact address
Sometimes a random nearby address 
etc...

Is there a way to return a list of results (i.e. multiple addresses that fit the general latitude/longitude of where I'm located?)

So maybe it'll give me the correct address plus a few nearby addresses it thinks I might be at?

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the maps tile from Googlemaps to get all locations in the area. The maps tile is easier to get with a geohash from your lat lon pair. I've evidence that Google uses a z-order morton curve but in the new googlemaps they uses a x,y pair to identify the tiles. Here is a link from Microsoft explaining bing maps quadkey: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx. I've wrote a php script for use with Googlemaps and hilbert curves. I mainly wrote it because I wanted some clustering and fast lookups but you can also use it to draw some hilbert curves. You can download it for free at phpclasses.org (hilbert curve). Maybe you can look into R-Trees because they are less complicated.

Comment: This sounds like is has potential, do you have a link pointing to more information about this? Thanks